# Perl script writing output twice; second time in reverse order

Tags: perl

I'm trying to figure out why a script is writing output twice. The first time in proper order, the second time in reverse order. It should only be writing it once.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use warnings;
use strict;
use Fcntl ':mode';
use File::Find;
no warnings 'File::Find';
no warnings 'uninitialized';

my $dir = "/var/log/tivoli/";
my $mtab = "/etc/mtab";
my $permFile = "world_writable_files.txt";
my $tmpFile = "world_writable_files.tmp";
my $exclude = "/usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt";
my $mask = S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH;
my (%excludes, %devNums);
my $errHeader;

# Compile a list of mountpoints that need to be scanned
my @mounts;

open MT, "<${mtab}" or die "Cannot open ${mtab}, $!";

# We only want the local mountpoints
while (<MT>) {
  if ($_ =~ /ext[34]/) {
    chomp;
    my @line = split;
    push(@mounts, $line[1]);
    my @stats = stat($line[1]);
    $devNums{$stats[0]} = undef;
  }
}

close MT;

# Build a hash from /usr/local/etc/world_writables_excludes.txt
if ((! -e $exclude) || (-z $exclude)) {
  $errHeader = <<HEADER;
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!                                                  !!
!! /usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt is    !!
!! is missing or empty. This report includes        !!
!! every world-writable file including those which  !!
!! are expected and should be excluded.             !!
!!                                                  !!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


HEADER

} else {
  open XCLD, "<${exclude}" or die "Cannot open ${exclude}, $!\n";
  while (<XCLD>) {
    chomp;
    $excludes{$_} = 1;
  }
}

sub wanted {
  my @dirStats = stat($File::Find::name);

  # Is it excluded from the report...
  return if exists $excludes{$File::Find::name};

  # ...is the Tivoli installation directory or a special directory...
  if ($File::Find::name =~ m{^/sys|^/proc|^/dev|^/opt/IBM/ITM}) {
    $File::Find::prune = 1;
    return;
  }

  # ...a regular file, ...
  return unless -f;

  # ...local, ...
  return unless (exists $devNums{$dirStats[0]});

  # ...and world writable?
  return unless ($dirStats[2] & $mask) == $mask;

  # If so, add the file to the list of world writable files
  print(WWFILE "$File::Find::name\n");

}

# Create the output file path if it doesn't already exist.
mkdir($dir or die "Cannot execute mkdir on ${dir}, $!") unless (-d $dir);

# Create our filehandle for writing our findings
open WWFILE, ">${dir}${tmpFile}" or die "Cannot open ${dir}${tmpFile}, $!";
print(WWFILE "${errHeader}") if ($errHeader);

find(\&wanted, @mounts);

close WWFILE;

# If no world-writable files have been found ${tmpFile} should be zero-size;
# Delete it so Tivoli won't alert
if (-z "${dir}${tmpFile}") {
  unlink "${dir}${tmpFile}";

} else {
  rename("${dir}${tmpFile}","${dir}${permFile}") or die "Cannot rename file ${dir}${tmpFile}, $!";

}
```

Example output:

```
# cat world_writable_files.txt 
/var/opt/ds_agent/am/diagnostic_1.log
/home/User1/report.pl.20130220
/home/User1/report.pl.20130220
/var/opt/ds_agent/am/diagnostic_1.log
```

Each file is being written only once in the script so I am wondering if the filesystem is being scanned twice. Once in each direction. I don't see where that would be happening, but I don't know.

Excludes file:

```
# cat /usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt 
/var/opt/ds_agent/diagnostic.log
/var/opt/ds_agent/am/diagnostic.log
```

Any thoughts on this conundrum?

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code, specifically where you get the file list and where you print it out?

Comment: I've already posted the entire script. That's all of it. Did you scroll through it?

Comment: @CDahn it gets printed in the `wanted` subrountine. theillien, I'm not sure, but try print `@mounts` before you call `find(\&wanted, @mounts);`. Since "find() does a depth-first search over the given @directories in the order they are given. For each file or directory found, it calls the &wanted subroutine." I'm thinking it found those files twice, but I don't really know and could be completely wrong.

Comment: Weird, it's not rendering correctly for me. Go figure.

Comment: printing `@mounts` produces `# /home/msnyder/ww_files-v4-4.pl 
/ /boot /home /opt /var /ecap /log_archives`

Comment: I tried `finddepth()` to see if it would make a difference. It didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `@mounts` has `/` in addition to `/home` and `/var`. So you're asking it to scan everything at and below `/` (including `/home` and `/var`), then to scan everything at and below `/home`, then to scan everything at and below `/var`.

It's better to identify the places you want to avoid.

```
while (<MT>) {
   my @fields = split;
   if ($field[2] !~ /^ext[34]\z/) {
      ++$excludes{ $fields[1] };
   }
}

find(\&wanted, '/');

sub wanted {
   if ($excludes{$File::Find::name}) {
      $File::Find::prune = 1;
      return;
   }

   my @dirStats = stat($File::Find::name);

   return if !-f;
   return if $dirStats[2] & S_IWOTH;

   print(WWFILE "$File::Find::name\n");
}
```

You won't need `if ($File::Find::name =~ m{^/sys|^/proc|^/dev|^/opt/IBM/ITM})` anymore because they're not ext3 or ext4. Except maybe for `/opt/IBM/ITM` (since I don't know what that is). If you did have some files or directories you wanted to skip, add them to `%excludes` rather than making a relatively expensive regex match.

```
++$excludes{$_} for qw( /foo /bar /opt/IBM/ITM );
```

Comment: This is interesting. Would it be feasible to, instead of `++$excludes{$_} for qw( /sys /proc /dev/ /opt/IBM/ITM );`, add those directories to my excludes file and have them added in the same manner? Ideally I'd prefer keeping those hard coded in the script itself.

Comment: First, note the update. Secondly, up to you whether it's hardcoded (as shown) or in your file.

Comment: I changed the `while` loop to what you've suggested and added the block that sets `$File::Find::prune = 1`. Nothing else so far. It has thrown an error: `invalid top directory at /usr/share/perl5/File/Find.pm line 598, <XCLD> line 2.`. I've added the exclude file to my post for reference.

Comment: You didn't pass a directory to `find`. Are you still using `find(\&wanted, @mounts);`?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment (this one prior to editing). I have gone ahead and added all of the code you provided and it is doing what it should including removing the need to hard-code the directories. Those are now part of the excludes file.

Comment: Now I just need to go through and make sure I understand what the code is doing.

Comment: Interestingly, while I can see that `/proc` (or rather `proc`) is being added to `%excludes` it still shows up in results. I have to add it to the excludes file for it to actually be ignored. Instead, I used `++$excludes{ $fields[1] }` which did properly ignore it.

Comment: Oops, yeah, should be `$fields[1]`. Fixed.